# Combine multiple threshold for inRange

Tags: c++, opencv, hsv

I want to combine multiple threshold for detecting different type of red colour. I tried to make 4 type of thresholding and then I combine the result of 4 image into 1. but the result is always pitch black. is there any other way to do it? I guess the way I'm combining the 2 image into 1 is not correct using the addWeighted

```
Mat img = imread (nameImg);
cvtColor(img , hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
Mat bw,bw2,bw3,bw4;
inRange(hsv, Scalar(0,28,192), Scalar(4,67,219),bw); // detecting acne 1
inRange(hsv, Scalar(0,40,152), Scalar(8,85,243),bw2); // acne 2
inRange(hsv, Scalar(0,85,202), Scalar(6,146,247),bw3); // acne 3
inRange(hsv, Scalar(156,93,176), Scalar(82,130,255),bw4); // acne 4

vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<vector<Point> > contours2;
vector<vector<Point> > contours3;
vector<vector<Point> > contours4;

findContours(bw.clone(),  contours,  CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
findContours(bw2.clone(), contours2, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
findContours(bw3.clone(), contours3, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
findContours(bw4.clone(), contours4, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

Mat dst = Mat::zeros(img.size(), img.type());
drawContours(dst, contours, -1, Scalar::all(255), CV_FILLED);
Mat dst2 = Mat::zeros(img.size(), img.type());
drawContours(dst2, contours2, -1, Scalar::all(255), CV_FILLED);
Mat dst3 = Mat::zeros(img.size(), img.type());
drawContours(dst3, contours4, -1, Scalar::all(255), CV_FILLED);
Mat dst4 = Mat::zeros(img.size(), img.type());
drawContours(dst4, contours4, -1, Scalar::all(255), CV_FILLED);
Mat dst5, dst6;
imshow("dst",dst);
imshow("dst2",dst2);
imshow("dst3",dst3);
imshow("dst4",dst4);

addWeighted(dst, 0.5, dst2, 0.5, 0,dst5);//combine acne 1 with 2
addWeighted(dst4, 0.5, dst3, 0.5, 0,dst6); //combine acne 3 with 4
addWeighted(dst5, 0.5, dst6, 0.5, 0,out);
imshow("result",out); //the result always black
```

Comment: have you tried bitwise_and ?

Comment: bitwise_and make it worse. i've tried bitwise_or but it still doesn't give the maximum result